Need to Fetch the Bundle Id and App Store Id
I need to find the bundle ID or app store ID.
I checked Roku App Info here => https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/components/roappinfo.md
But not able to find a specific word for this is bundle id or app store ID
can anyone suggest where I can find the bundle and app store URL.

"GetId" => Is my bundle and app store ID?
